# hello, iam practicing on kivymd, and when i run my code it shows me 'unnamed window ' can someone help me?

Tags: python, kivy, window, kivymd

[when i run my code it shows me 'unnamed window'!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW4k6.png)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

username_helper = """
MDTextField:
    hint_text: "Enter useraname"
    helper_text: "or click or forgot username"
    helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
    icon_right: "android"
    icon_right_color:ap.theme_cls.primary_color
    pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint_x:None 
    width:300
"""

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        #username = MDTextField(text='Enter Username',
           #                      pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            #                     size_hint_x=None, width=300)

        username=Builder.load_string(username_helper)
        screen.add_widget(username)
        return screen
DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please take the time to do the [tour] and learn how to [ask]. Your body text is now in the *question* field which makes it nearly impossible to find for other users that might be interested in a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your line in the `kv` string:

```
icon_right_color:ap.theme_cls.primary_color
```

should be:

```
icon_right_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
```

just a typo.